# SQL statement including MakeValid() crushing the server

Tags: sql-server, gis, geospatial, spatial, sqlgeometry

I think this is an interesting bug with `MakeValid()` in SQL Server I have tried it in SQL Server 2016 and 2019. The following SQL will crush your SQL Server and you'll have to kill the SQL Server Service. There is nothing special about this geometry. We have been doing this with millions of geometries for the last 5 years, but found a needle in the haystack that brings the server down.

```
declare @wkt nvarchar(max) = 'MULTILINESTRING ((-78.063088844296 39.0923128276227, -78.0629933704493 39.0924209049056, -78.0628537704575 39.0925804994165, -78.0626985415764 39.0927655959674, -78.0625776031863 39.0929093443343, -78.0624772451994 39.0930271271681, -78.0624404735616 39.093069429965, -78.06242230244 39.0931060149791, -78.062417726422 39.0931460260255, -78.0624230534316 39.0931855915373, -78.0624414338606 39.0932160425133, -78.0624617321928 39.0932363736011, -78.0624857549401 39.0932547887746, -78.0625955308645 39.0933174085555, -78.0628091268828 39.0934413211804, -78.0623615448858 39.0939008841112, -78.0618945628718 39.0943812788732, -78.0621603492116 39.094522628407, -78.0625166974101 39.0947133754383, -78.0627689030194 39.0948489021124, -78.0630246488892 39.0949866567258, -78.0632038915344 39.0950820335129, -78.0632954936423 39.095126900709, -78.0633505648608 39.0951567951925, -78.0635673364237 39.0952755726356, -78.063682189626 39.0953377527927), (-78.0636821896416 39.0953377528011, -78.063757905942 39.0953787442108, -78.0639711453292 39.0954941852792, -78.0641092846603 39.0955700222676, -78.0644398539051 39.0957485791264, -78.064783336432 39.0959347898128, -78.06514128453 39.096126566234, -78.0651655623989 39.0961381922841, -78.0654659698097 39.0958486496622, -78.0653479527409 39.0956841997381, -78.0648892954147 39.0954718713677, -78.0645701123162 39.0955967701995, -78.0644398539051 39.0957485791264, -78.0641092846603 39.0955700222676, -78.0639711453292 39.0954941852792, -78.063757905942 39.0953787442108, -78.0635673364393 39.095275572644, -78.0633505648764 39.0951567952009, -78.0632954936579 39.0951269007174, -78.06320389155 39.0950820335213, -78.0630246489048 39.0949866567342, -78.062768903035 39.0948489021208, -78.0625166974257 39.0947133754467, -78.0621603492272 39.0945226284154, -78.0618945628874 39.0943812788816, -78.0617054459606 39.0942782571458, -78.0615781367185 39.094207817123, -78.0613182406321 39.0940655626988, -78.0611270926144 39.0939594435658, -78.0609317701255 39.0938510242263, -78.0607352124531 39.0937393369615, -78.0605369866093 39.0936266643798, -78.0603537707155 39.0935248163208, -78.0602511013634 39.0934677492167), (-78.0602511013634 39.0934677492167, -78.0600742383553 39.0933694413094, -78.0604932584179 39.0928866824054, -78.0608162054575 39.0930709352344, -78.0610014102213 39.0931742989685, -78.0612692959238 39.093305320502, -78.061566316686 39.0934705247655, -78.0621024968246 39.0937608119971, -78.0622390120017 39.0938294697379, -78.0623615449014 39.0939008841196, -78.0618945628874 39.0943812788816, -78.0617054459606 39.0942782571458, -78.0615781367185 39.094207817123, -78.0613182406321 39.0940655626988, -78.0611270926144 39.0939594435658, -78.0609317701255 39.0938510242263, -78.0607352124531 39.0937393369615, -78.0605369866093 39.0936266643798, -78.0603537707155 39.0935248163208, -78.0603424456547 39.0935185213164), (-78.060342445643 39.0935185213101, -78.0600742383436 39.0933694413031, -78.0604932584062 39.0928866823991, -78.0608162054458 39.0930709352281, -78.0610014102096 39.0931742989622, -78.0612692959121 39.0933053204957, -78.0615663166743 39.0934705247592, -78.0621024968129 39.0937608119908, -78.06223901199 39.0938294697316, -78.0623615448897 39.0939008841133, -78.0618945628757 39.0943812788753, -78.0621603492155 39.0945226284091, -78.062516697414 39.0947133754404, -78.0627689030233 39.0948489021145, -78.0630246488931 39.0949866567279, -78.0632038915383 39.095082033515, -78.0632954936462 39.0951269007111, -78.0633505648647 39.0951567951946, -78.0635673364276 39.0952755726377, -78.0637579059303 39.0953787442045, -78.0639711453175 39.0954941852729, -78.0641092846486 39.0955700222613, -78.0644398538934 39.0957485791201, -78.0641672852732 39.0960441025072, -78.0636611852219 39.0965910448198), (-78.063661185218 39.0965910448177, -78.0636370870122 39.0966170875257, -78.0630339329776 39.0962933813165, -78.0621979068753 39.0958332797234, -78.0619819914069 39.0960652526533, -78.0619241515807 39.0961326818238, -78.0618918077389 39.0961804325525, -78.0618661401763 39.0962282083471, -78.0618577957256 39.0962822921137, -78.0618508382737 39.0963280558047, -78.0618559182467 39.0963707428539, -78.0618703344103 39.0964155450904, -78.0618861115217 39.0964561900775, -78.0619152375981 39.0964979254134, -78.0619444328449 39.0965282139131, -78.0619829777571 39.096558536561, -78.062052145339 39.0966029963687, -78.0634884796131 39.0973721601295, -78.0637108737313 39.0971400255744, -78.0637686336075 39.0970732038992, -78.0637898392381 39.0970442332728, -78.0638072674529 39.0970078001921, -78.0638219225684 39.0969557157526, -78.0638298699638 39.0969065851623, -78.0638283122851 39.0968484820183, -78.0638161769439 39.0968007672974, -78.0637944736466 39.0967545061364, -78.063758437729 39.0967074480832, -78.0637194975581 39.0966663375332, -78.0636871267668 39.0966453618572, -78.0636370870122 39.0966170875257, -78.0636920082121 39.0965577341202), (-78.0636920082121 39.0965577341202, -78.0638980790433 39.0963350337855), (-78.0638980790446 39.0963350337862, -78.0641672852706 39.0960441025058, -78.0644398538908 39.0957485791187, -78.0647833364177 39.0959347898051, -78.0651412845157 39.0961265662263, -78.0651655623846 39.0961381922764, -78.0654659697954 39.0958486496545, -78.0653479527266 39.0956841997304, -78.0648892954004 39.09547187136, -78.0645701123019 39.0955967701918, -78.0644398538908 39.0957485791187, -78.0641672852706 39.0960441025058, -78.0636370870135 39.0966170875264, -78.0636871267681 39.0966453618579, -78.0637194975594 39.0966663375339, -78.0637584377303 39.0967074480839, -78.0637944736479 39.0967545061371, -78.0638161769452 39.0968007672981, -78.0638283122864 39.096848482019, -78.0638298699651 39.096906585163, -78.0638219225697 39.0969557157533, -78.0638072674542 39.0970078001928, -78.0637898392394 39.0970442332735, -78.0637686336088 39.0970732038999, -78.0637108737326 39.0971400255751, -78.0634884796144 39.0973721601302, -78.0634166790704 39.0973337110302), (-78.0634166790938 39.0973337110428, -78.0624792296026 39.0968317033473), (-78.0624792296026 39.0968317033473, -78.0621042503451 39.0966308991288), (-78.0621042503425 39.0966308991274, -78.0620521453611 39.0966029963806, -78.0619829777792 39.0965585365729, -78.061944432867 39.096528213925, -78.0619152376202 39.0964979254253, -78.0618861115438 39.0964561900894, -78.0618703344324 39.0964155451023, -78.0618559182688 39.0963707428658, -78.0618508382958 39.0963280558166, -78.0618577957477 39.0962822921256, -78.0618661401984 39.096228208359, -78.061891807761 39.0961804325644, -78.0619241516028 39.0961326818357, -78.061981991429 39.0960652526652, -78.0621979068974 39.0958332797353, -78.0630339329997 39.0962933813284, -78.0636370870343 39.0966170875376, -78.0636871267889 39.0966453618691, -78.0637194975802 39.0966663375451, -78.0637584377511 39.0967074480951, -78.0637944736687 39.0967545061483, -78.063816176966 39.0968007673093, -78.0638283123072 39.0968484820302, -78.0638298699859 39.0969065851742, -78.0638219225905 39.0969557157644, -78.063807267475 39.097007800204, -78.0637898392602 39.0970442332847, -78.0637686336296 39.0970732039111, -78.0637108737534 39.0971400255863, -78.0634884796352 39.0973721601414, -78.0622917404204 39.0967313009596), (-78.0622917404204 39.0967313009596, -78.0620521453611 39.0966029963806, -78.0619829777792 39.0965585365729, -78.061944432867 39.096528213925, -78.0619152376202 39.0964979254253, -78.0618861115438 39.0964561900894, -78.0618703344324 39.0964155451023, -78.0618559182688 39.0963707428658, -78.0618508382958 39.0963280558166, -78.0618577957477 39.0962822921256, -78.0618661401984 39.096228208359, -78.061891807761 39.0961804325644, -78.0619241516028 39.0961326818357, -78.061981991429 39.0960652526652, -78.0621979068974 39.0958332797353, -78.0630339329997 39.0962933813284, -78.0636370870343 39.0966170875376, -78.0641672852914 39.096044102517, -78.0644398539116 39.0957485791299, -78.0641092846668 39.0955700222711, -78.0639711453357 39.0954941852827, -78.0637579059485 39.0953787442143, -78.0635673364458 39.0952755726475, -78.0633505648829 39.0951567952044, -78.0632954936644 39.0951269007209, -78.0632038915565 39.0950820335248, -78.0630246489113 39.0949866567377, -78.0627689030415 39.0948489021243, -78.0625166974322 39.0947133754502, -78.0623137733994 39.0946047536911), (-78.0623137733851 39.0946047536834, -78.0621603492194 39.0945226284112, -78.0618945628796 39.0943812788774, -78.061888890917 39.0943781889316), (-78.061888890917 39.0943781889316, -78.0617054459528 39.0942782571416, -78.0615781367107 39.0942078171189, -78.0613182406243 39.0940655626946, -78.0611270926066 39.0939594435616, -78.0609317701177 39.0938510242221, -78.0607352124453 39.0937393369573, -78.0605369866015 39.0936266643756, -78.0603537707077 39.0935248163166, -78.0600742383475 39.0933694413052, -78.0604932584101 39.0928866824012, -78.0608162054497 39.0930709352302, -78.0610014102135 39.0931742989643, -78.061269295916 39.0933053204978, -78.0615663166782 39.0934705247613, -78.0621024968168 39.0937608119929, -78.0622390119939 39.0938294697337, -78.0623615448936 39.0939008841154, -78.0618945628796 39.0943812788774, -78.0621603492194 39.0945226284112, -78.0625166974179 39.0947133754425, -78.0627689030272 39.0948489021166, -78.063024648897 39.09498665673, -78.0632038915422 39.0950820335171, -78.0632954936501 39.0951269007132, -78.0633505648686 39.0951567951967, -78.0635673364315 39.0952755726398, -78.0637579059342 39.0953787442066, -78.0639711453214 39.095494185275, -78.0641092846525 39.0955700222634, -78.0644398538973 39.0957485791222, -78.0641672852771 39.0960441025093, -78.06363708702 39.0966170875299, -78.0630339329854 39.0962933813207, -78.0621979068831 39.0958332797276, -78.0621805909577 39.0958241843748), (-78.062180590959 39.0958241843755, -78.0616206090586 39.0955300516351, -78.0621979068844 39.0958332797283, -78.061981991416 39.0960652526582, -78.0619241515898 39.0961326818287, -78.061891807748 39.0961804325574, -78.0618917260013 39.0961805838438), (-78.0618917260117 39.0961805838494, -78.0618661401958 39.0962282083576, -78.0618577957451 39.0962822921242, -78.0618508382932 39.0963280558152, -78.0618559182662 39.0963707428644, -78.0618703344298 39.0964155451009, -78.0618861115412 39.096456190088, -78.0619152376176 39.0964979254239, -78.0619444328644 39.0965282139236, -78.0619829777766 39.0965585365715, -78.0620521453585 39.0966029963792, -78.0634884796326 39.09737216014, -78.0637108737508 39.0971400255849, -78.063768633627 39.0970732039097, -78.0637898392576 39.0970442332833, -78.0638072674724 39.0970078002026, -78.0638219225879 39.096955715763, -78.0638298699833 39.0969065851728, -78.0638283123046 39.0968484820288, -78.0638161769634 39.0968007673079, -78.0637944736661 39.0967545061469, -78.0637584377485 39.0967074480937, -78.0637194975776 39.0966663375437, -78.0636871267863 39.0966453618677, -78.0636370870317 39.0966170875362, -78.0630339329971 39.096293381327, -78.0621979068948 39.0958332797339, -78.0621805900711 39.0958241843811), (-78.0621805900711 39.0958241843811, -78.061620609069 39.0955300516407, -78.0621979068948 39.0958332797339, -78.0630339329971 39.096293381327, -78.0636370870317 39.0966170875362, -78.0641672852888 39.0960441025156, -78.064439853909 39.0957485791285, -78.0641092846642 39.0955700222697, -78.0639711453331 39.0954941852813, -78.0637579059459 39.0953787442129, -78.0635673364432 39.0952755726461, -78.0633505648803 39.095156795203, -78.0632954936618 39.0951269007195, -78.0632038915539 39.0950820335234, -78.0630246489087 39.0949866567363, -78.0627689030389 39.0948489021229, -78.0625166974296 39.0947133754488, -78.0621603492311 39.0945226284175, -78.0618945628913 39.0943812788837, -78.0617054459645 39.0942782571479, -78.061321075719 39.094762278193, -78.06117171643 39.0949581928028, -78.0611668089336 39.0949645908619), (-78.0611668089323 39.0949645908612, -78.0609227959584 39.0952826908637, -78.0608782619782 39.0953392384941, -78.0608407240774 39.0953850090718, -78.060819789738 39.0954078863319, -78.0607980307452 39.0954240093091, -78.0607754336243 39.0954354026171, -78.0607554685671 39.095441404635, -78.0607268446489 39.0954466990153, -78.0606973861958 39.0954465895581, -78.0606688080916 39.0954444568864, -78.060639408029 39.0954348950704, -78.060603123278 39.0954178811002, -78.0599165840255 39.095049383042, -78.0595054754256 39.0948371970775, -78.0594492552619 39.0948081321096), (-78.0594492552541 39.0948081321054, -78.0590503242162 39.0946018903349, -78.0588067801629 39.0944747238768, -78.0586265790152 39.0943747998927, -78.058662242132 39.0943616292758, -78.0587202032307 39.0943388925086, -78.0588941314428 39.0942634564754, -78.0589635541463 39.0942316659499, -78.0590346342414 39.0941972246871, -78.0591063817849 39.0941612467963, -78.0591711000112 39.0941266109824, -78.0592624775402 39.0940737805097, -78.059423526606 39.0939658145222, -78.0595277491453 39.0938935412623, -78.0595912196117 39.0938476156364, -78.0596474577418 39.0938004664022, -78.059706574074 39.0937490537822, -78.0597932695837 39.0936726110627, -78.0598449245092 39.0936215120883, -78.0598954843883 39.0935698964531, -78.0599705548 39.093492897175, -78.0600742383501 39.0933694413066, -78.0603537707103 39.093524816318, -78.0605369866041 39.093626664377, -78.0607352124479 39.0937393369587, -78.0609317701203 39.0938510242235, -78.0611270926092 39.093959443563, -78.0613182406269 39.094065562696, -78.0615781367133 39.0942078171202, -78.0617054459554 39.094278257143, -78.0618945628822 39.0943812788788, -78.062160349222 39.0945226284126, -78.0625166974205 39.0947133754439, -78.0627689030298 39.094848902118, -78.0630246488996 39.0949866567314, -78.0632038915448 39.0950820335185, -78.0632954936527 39.0951269007146, -78.0636763667567 39.0947529812103, -78.063979456537 39.0946417743417, -78.0645934164061 39.0949256008234))'
declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText(@wkt, 4326)
select @g.MakeValid()
```

Has anybody encountered anything like this?

Comment: Are you running the latest build of SQL Server 2019 with CU9?

Comment: The place to report SQL Server bugs is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). If anyone's feeling inspired, you can try reproducing and even debugging this by invoking the [`SqlGeography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.makevalid) classes directly in .NET; if the code isn't exactly what SQL Server uses (and I actually think it is, as the geography types are implemented with managed code) it'll at least be the moral equivalent (I have not done this myself). Note that this type is still closed source.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, yes we are running latest build of 2019 with CU9.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, calling [`MakeValid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.makevalid) from the [`SqlGeography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography) class in .NET for the same geometry text does not fail.  Sample code (as Gist) [here](https://gist.github.com/anotherlab/44a706a3792cf079f1e2512b4695447d).

Comment: @ChrisMiller: Note that here was a typo in my original comment: the class under use is `SqlGeometry`, not `SqlGeography`.

Comment: @Jeroen: I made the same typo in my comment.  My Gist code sample uses [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: [MultiLineString - Valid Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/multilinestring?view=sql-server-ver15#valid-instances) this input shape *CANNOT* be valid as a single `MultiLineString` because it violates both of the following criteria:

> For a MultiLineString instance to be valid it must meet the following criteria:
>
> - All instances comprising the MultiLineString instance must be valid LineString instances.
> - No two LineString instances comprising the MultiLineString instance may overlap over an interval. The LineString instances can only intersect or touch themselves or other LineString instances at a finite number of points.
>   , nor can it be made to be valid.

So to make this valid, first you would have to make all the component lines valid independantly, then you would likely still run into issues with the second constraint, its hard to show in a simple proof, but when you render all those lines independently it is clear that most of them directly overlap each other:

[image: overlapping lines]

Instead of using *GEOMETRY* we could (and *SHOULD*) use `GEOGRAPHY` as these points smell like GPS coordinates, but we can easily use `STBuffer()` to produce an exanded representation of the lines to try to detail the areas of intersection:

[image: overlapping geography lines]

> So here I have tried to label the lines with the number of intersects with other lines in the same set in brackets, for instance `14:(4)` indicates that the 14th line in the set intersects with 4 other lines at some point.
>
> > Lines 13 and 16 are the worst offenders, intersecting with 13 other lines each.
> >
> > Line 13 for instance:
> > [image: Line 13]

I haven't researched it, but [`MakeValid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/makevalid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) probably tries a number of algorithms to forcibly make a line or the MultiLineString valid. One would assume by changing the start point in the series, detecting closures and overlaps, or to reverse the direction of the [Left Hand Rule](https://bertwagner.com/posts/inverted-polygons-how-to-troubleshoot-sql-servers-left-hand-rule/).

But in this given data set, the overlapping lines presents what should effectively be a *stack overflow* exception because there is an infinite number of permutations to try to resolve the conflicts.

The closest error I can trap is this `Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program`:

[image: memory exception message]

---

The problem with reporting this as a bug is that we only really know it is a bug after it has failed, to build in some complexity to the runtime to deal with this is counter intuitive, or at least it would lead to introduction of or usage of environment variable or query hints like `MAXDOP` or `MAXRECURSION` to allow the caller to control the level of effort or time that should be allowed before MakeValid() would fail.

In this case, where it is clear that multiple lines intersect over many segments, `MultiLineString` is not a valid type of shape to represent this data, instead it should be processed as multiple records of `LineString`

---

The following SQL was used in this proof, originally I found that only 2 lines were implicitly valid in their own right, the following overlays these lines so we can see they would still violate the MultiLineString criteria regardless of their validity:

```
WITH lines as (SELECT * FROM
(VALUES (1,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.063088844296 39.0923128276227, -78.0629933704493 39.0924209049056, -78.0628537704575 39.0925804994165, -78.0626985415764 39.0927655959674, -78.0625776031863 39.0929093443343, -78.0624772451994 39.0930271271681, -78.0624404735616 39.093069429965, -78.06242230244 39.0931060149791, -78.062417726422 39.0931460260255, -78.0624230534316 39.0931855915373, -78.0624414338606 39.0932160425133, -78.0624617321928 39.0932363736011, -78.0624857549401 39.0932547887746, -78.0625955308645 39.0933174085555, -78.0628091268828 39.0934413211804, -78.0623615448858 39.0939008841112, -78.0618945628718 39.0943812788732, -78.0621603492116 39.094522628407, -78.0625166974101 39.0947133754383, -78.0627689030194 39.0948489021124, -78.0630246488892 39.0949866567258, -78.0632038915344 39.0950820335129, -78.0632954936423 39.095126900709, -78.0633505648608 39.0951567951925, -78.0635673364237 39.0952755726356, -78.063682189626 39.0953377527927)', 4326))
       ,(2,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0636821896416 39.0953377528011, -78.063757905942 39.0953787442108, -78.0639711453292 39.0954941852792, -78.0641092846603 39.0955700222676, -78.0644398539051 39.0957485791264, -78.064783336432 39.0959347898128, -78.06514128453 39.096126566234, -78.0651655623989 39.0961381922841, -78.0654659698097 39.0958486496622, -78.0653479527409 39.0956841997381, -78.0648892954147 39.0954718713677, -78.0645701123162 39.0955967701995, -78.0644398539051 39.0957485791264, -78.0641092846603 39.0955700222676, -78.0639711453292 39.0954941852792, -78.063757905942 39.0953787442108, -78.0635673364393 39.095275572644, -78.0633505648764 39.0951567952009, -78.0632954936579 39.0951269007174, -78.06320389155 39.0950820335213, -78.0630246489048 39.0949866567342, -78.062768903035 39.0948489021208, -78.0625166974257 39.0947133754467, -78.0621603492272 39.0945226284154, -78.0618945628874 39.0943812788816, -78.0617054459606 39.0942782571458, -78.0615781367185 39.094207817123, -78.0613182406321 39.0940655626988, -78.0611270926144 39.0939594435658, -78.0609317701255 39.0938510242263, -78.0607352124531 39.0937393369615, -78.0605369866093 39.0936266643798, -78.0603537707155 39.0935248163208, -78.0602511013634 39.0934677492167)', 4326))
       ,(3,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0602511013634 39.0934677492167, -78.0600742383553 39.0933694413094, -78.0604932584179 39.0928866824054, -78.0608162054575 39.0930709352344, -78.0610014102213 39.0931742989685, -78.0612692959238 39.093305320502, -78.061566316686 39.0934705247655, -78.0621024968246 39.0937608119971, -78.0622390120017 39.0938294697379, -78.0623615449014 39.0939008841196, -78.0618945628874 39.0943812788816, -78.0617054459606 39.0942782571458, -78.0615781367185 39.094207817123, -78.0613182406321 39.0940655626988, -78.0611270926144 39.0939594435658, -78.0609317701255 39.0938510242263, -78.0607352124531 39.0937393369615, -78.0605369866093 39.0936266643798, -78.0603537707155 39.0935248163208, -78.0603424456547 39.0935185213164)',4326))
       ,(4,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.060342445643 39.0935185213101, -78.0600742383436 39.0933694413031, -78.0604932584062 39.0928866823991, -78.0608162054458 39.0930709352281, -78.0610014102096 39.0931742989622, -78.0612692959121 39.0933053204957, -78.0615663166743 39.0934705247592, -78.0621024968129 39.0937608119908, -78.06223901199 39.0938294697316, -78.0623615448897 39.0939008841133, -78.0618945628757 39.0943812788753, -78.0621603492155 39.0945226284091, -78.062516697414 39.0947133754404, -78.0627689030233 39.0948489021145, -78.0630246488931 39.0949866567279, -78.0632038915383 39.095082033515, -78.0632954936462 39.0951269007111, -78.0633505648647 39.0951567951946, -78.0635673364276 39.0952755726377, -78.0637579059303 39.0953787442045, -78.0639711453175 39.0954941852729, -78.0641092846486 39.0955700222613, -78.0644398538934 39.0957485791201, -78.0641672852732 39.0960441025072, -78.0636611852219 39.0965910448198)',4326))
       ,(5,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.063661185218 39.0965910448177, -78.0636370870122 39.0966170875257, -78.0630339329776 39.0962933813165, -78.0621979068753 39.0958332797234, -78.0619819914069 39.0960652526533, -78.0619241515807 39.0961326818238, -78.0618918077389 39.0961804325525, -78.0618661401763 39.0962282083471, -78.0618577957256 39.0962822921137, -78.0618508382737 39.0963280558047, -78.0618559182467 39.0963707428539, -78.0618703344103 39.0964155450904, -78.0618861115217 39.0964561900775, -78.0619152375981 39.0964979254134, -78.0619444328449 39.0965282139131, -78.0619829777571 39.096558536561, -78.062052145339 39.0966029963687, -78.0634884796131 39.0973721601295, -78.0637108737313 39.0971400255744, -78.0637686336075 39.0970732038992, -78.0637898392381 39.0970442332728, -78.0638072674529 39.0970078001921, -78.0638219225684 39.0969557157526, -78.0638298699638 39.0969065851623, -78.0638283122851 39.0968484820183, -78.0638161769439 39.0968007672974, -78.0637944736466 39.0967545061364, -78.063758437729 39.0967074480832, -78.0637194975581 39.0966663375332, -78.0636871267668 39.0966453618572, -78.0636370870122 39.0966170875257, -78.0636920082121 39.0965577341202)',4326))
       ,(6,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0636920082121 39.0965577341202, -78.0638980790433 39.0963350337855)',4326))
       ,(7,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0638980790446 39.0963350337862, -78.0641672852706 39.0960441025058, -78.0644398538908 39.0957485791187, -78.0647833364177 39.0959347898051, -78.0651412845157 39.0961265662263, -78.0651655623846 39.0961381922764, -78.0654659697954 39.0958486496545, -78.0653479527266 39.0956841997304, -78.0648892954004 39.09547187136, -78.0645701123019 39.0955967701918, -78.0644398538908 39.0957485791187, -78.0641672852706 39.0960441025058, -78.0636370870135 39.0966170875264, -78.0636871267681 39.0966453618579, -78.0637194975594 39.0966663375339, -78.0637584377303 39.0967074480839, -78.0637944736479 39.0967545061371, -78.0638161769452 39.0968007672981, -78.0638283122864 39.096848482019, -78.0638298699651 39.096906585163, -78.0638219225697 39.0969557157533, -78.0638072674542 39.0970078001928, -78.0637898392394 39.0970442332735, -78.0637686336088 39.0970732038999, -78.0637108737326 39.0971400255751, -78.0634884796144 39.0973721601302, -78.0634166790704 39.0973337110302)',4326))
       ,(8,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0634166790938 39.0973337110428, -78.0624792296026 39.0968317033473)',4326))
       ,(9,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0624792296026 39.0968317033473, -78.0621042503451 39.0966308991288)',4326))
       ,(10,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0621042503425 39.0966308991274, -78.0620521453611 39.0966029963806, -78.0619829777792 39.0965585365729, -78.061944432867 39.096528213925, -78.0619152376202 39.0964979254253, -78.0618861115438 39.0964561900894, -78.0618703344324 39.0964155451023, -78.0618559182688 39.0963707428658, -78.0618508382958 39.0963280558166, -78.0618577957477 39.0962822921256, -78.0618661401984 39.096228208359, -78.061891807761 39.0961804325644, -78.0619241516028 39.0961326818357, -78.061981991429 39.0960652526652, -78.0621979068974 39.0958332797353, -78.0630339329997 39.0962933813284, -78.0636370870343 39.0966170875376, -78.0636871267889 39.0966453618691, -78.0637194975802 39.0966663375451, -78.0637584377511 39.0967074480951, -78.0637944736687 39.0967545061483, -78.063816176966 39.0968007673093, -78.0638283123072 39.0968484820302, -78.0638298699859 39.0969065851742, -78.0638219225905 39.0969557157644, -78.063807267475 39.097007800204, -78.0637898392602 39.0970442332847, -78.0637686336296 39.0970732039111, -78.0637108737534 39.0971400255863, -78.0634884796352 39.0973721601414, -78.0622917404204 39.0967313009596)',4326))
       ,(11,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0622917404204 39.0967313009596, -78.0620521453611 39.0966029963806, -78.0619829777792 39.0965585365729, -78.061944432867 39.096528213925, -78.0619152376202 39.0964979254253, -78.0618861115438 39.0964561900894, -78.0618703344324 39.0964155451023, -78.0618559182688 39.0963707428658, -78.0618508382958 39.0963280558166, -78.0618577957477 39.0962822921256, -78.0618661401984 39.096228208359, -78.061891807761 39.0961804325644, -78.0619241516028 39.0961326818357, -78.061981991429 39.0960652526652, -78.0621979068974 39.0958332797353, -78.0630339329997 39.0962933813284, -78.0636370870343 39.0966170875376, -78.0641672852914 39.096044102517, -78.0644398539116 39.0957485791299, -78.0641092846668 39.0955700222711, -78.0639711453357 39.0954941852827, -78.0637579059485 39.0953787442143, -78.0635673364458 39.0952755726475, -78.0633505648829 39.0951567952044, -78.0632954936644 39.0951269007209, -78.0632038915565 39.0950820335248, -78.0630246489113 39.0949866567377, -78.0627689030415 39.0948489021243, -78.0625166974322 39.0947133754502, -78.0623137733994 39.0946047536911)',4326))
       ,(12,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0623137733851 39.0946047536834, -78.0621603492194 39.0945226284112, -78.0618945628796 39.0943812788774, -78.061888890917 39.0943781889316)',4326))
       ,(13,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.061888890917 39.0943781889316, -78.0617054459528 39.0942782571416, -78.0615781367107 39.0942078171189, -78.0613182406243 39.0940655626946, -78.0611270926066 39.0939594435616, -78.0609317701177 39.0938510242221, -78.0607352124453 39.0937393369573, -78.0605369866015 39.0936266643756, -78.0603537707077 39.0935248163166, -78.0600742383475 39.0933694413052, -78.0604932584101 39.0928866824012, -78.0608162054497 39.0930709352302, -78.0610014102135 39.0931742989643, -78.061269295916 39.0933053204978, -78.0615663166782 39.0934705247613, -78.0621024968168 39.0937608119929, -78.0622390119939 39.0938294697337, -78.0623615448936 39.0939008841154, -78.0618945628796 39.0943812788774, -78.0621603492194 39.0945226284112, -78.0625166974179 39.0947133754425, -78.0627689030272 39.0948489021166, -78.063024648897 39.09498665673, -78.0632038915422 39.0950820335171, -78.0632954936501 39.0951269007132, -78.0633505648686 39.0951567951967, -78.0635673364315 39.0952755726398, -78.0637579059342 39.0953787442066, -78.0639711453214 39.095494185275, -78.0641092846525 39.0955700222634, -78.0644398538973 39.0957485791222, -78.0641672852771 39.0960441025093, -78.06363708702 39.0966170875299, -78.0630339329854 39.0962933813207, -78.0621979068831 39.0958332797276, -78.0621805909577 39.0958241843748)',4326))
       ,(14,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.062180590959 39.0958241843755, -78.0616206090586 39.0955300516351, -78.0621979068844 39.0958332797283, -78.061981991416 39.0960652526582, -78.0619241515898 39.0961326818287, -78.061891807748 39.0961804325574, -78.0618917260013 39.0961805838438)',4326))
       ,(15,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0618917260117 39.0961805838494, -78.0618661401958 39.0962282083576, -78.0618577957451 39.0962822921242, -78.0618508382932 39.0963280558152, -78.0618559182662 39.0963707428644, -78.0618703344298 39.0964155451009, -78.0618861115412 39.096456190088, -78.0619152376176 39.0964979254239, -78.0619444328644 39.0965282139236, -78.0619829777766 39.0965585365715, -78.0620521453585 39.0966029963792, -78.0634884796326 39.09737216014, -78.0637108737508 39.0971400255849, -78.063768633627 39.0970732039097, -78.0637898392576 39.0970442332833, -78.0638072674724 39.0970078002026, -78.0638219225879 39.096955715763, -78.0638298699833 39.0969065851728, -78.0638283123046 39.0968484820288, -78.0638161769634 39.0968007673079, -78.0637944736661 39.0967545061469, -78.0637584377485 39.0967074480937, -78.0637194975776 39.0966663375437, -78.0636871267863 39.0966453618677, -78.0636370870317 39.0966170875362, -78.0630339329971 39.096293381327, -78.0621979068948 39.0958332797339, -78.0621805900711 39.0958241843811)',4326))
       ,(16,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0621805900711 39.0958241843811, -78.061620609069 39.0955300516407, -78.0621979068948 39.0958332797339, -78.0630339329971 39.096293381327, -78.0636370870317 39.0966170875362, -78.0641672852888 39.0960441025156, -78.064439853909 39.0957485791285, -78.0641092846642 39.0955700222697, -78.0639711453331 39.0954941852813, -78.0637579059459 39.0953787442129, -78.0635673364432 39.0952755726461, -78.0633505648803 39.095156795203, -78.0632954936618 39.0951269007195, -78.0632038915539 39.0950820335234, -78.0630246489087 39.0949866567363, -78.0627689030389 39.0948489021229, -78.0625166974296 39.0947133754488, -78.0621603492311 39.0945226284175, -78.0618945628913 39.0943812788837, -78.0617054459645 39.0942782571479, -78.061321075719 39.094762278193, -78.06117171643 39.0949581928028, -78.0611668089336 39.0949645908619)',4326))
       ,(17,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0611668089323 39.0949645908612, -78.0609227959584 39.0952826908637, -78.0608782619782 39.0953392384941, -78.0608407240774 39.0953850090718, -78.060819789738 39.0954078863319, -78.0607980307452 39.0954240093091, -78.0607754336243 39.0954354026171, -78.0607554685671 39.095441404635, -78.0607268446489 39.0954466990153, -78.0606973861958 39.0954465895581, -78.0606688080916 39.0954444568864, -78.060639408029 39.0954348950704, -78.060603123278 39.0954178811002, -78.0599165840255 39.095049383042, -78.0595054754256 39.0948371970775, -78.0594492552619 39.0948081321096)',4326))
       ,(18,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-78.0594492552541 39.0948081321054, -78.0590503242162 39.0946018903349, -78.0588067801629 39.0944747238768, -78.0586265790152 39.0943747998927, -78.058662242132 39.0943616292758, -78.0587202032307 39.0943388925086, -78.0588941314428 39.0942634564754, -78.0589635541463 39.0942316659499, -78.0590346342414 39.0941972246871, -78.0591063817849 39.0941612467963, -78.0591711000112 39.0941266109824, -78.0592624775402 39.0940737805097, -78.059423526606 39.0939658145222, -78.0595277491453 39.0938935412623, -78.0595912196117 39.0938476156364, -78.0596474577418 39.0938004664022, -78.059706574074 39.0937490537822, -78.0597932695837 39.0936726110627, -78.0598449245092 39.0936215120883, -78.0598954843883 39.0935698964531, -78.0599705548 39.093492897175, -78.0600742383501 39.0933694413066, -78.0603537707103 39.093524816318, -78.0605369866041 39.093626664377, -78.0607352124479 39.0937393369587, -78.0609317701203 39.0938510242235, -78.0611270926092 39.093959443563, -78.0613182406269 39.094065562696, -78.0615781367133 39.0942078171202, -78.0617054459554 39.094278257143, -78.0618945628822 39.0943812788788, -78.062160349222 39.0945226284126, -78.0625166974205 39.0947133754439, -78.0627689030298 39.094848902118, -78.0630246488996 39.0949866567314, -78.0632038915448 39.0950820335185, -78.0632954936527 39.0951269007146, -78.0636763667567 39.0947529812103, -78.063979456537 39.0946417743417, -78.0645934164061 39.0949256008234)',4326))
) as Line(rn, geo))
, ValidLines as 
(
   SELECT rn, geo = geo.MakeValid() FROM Lines
)
SELECT src.*
, Label = CAST(rn as varchar) + ': (' + CAST((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ValidLines lkp WHERE src.geo.STIntersects(lkp.geo) = 1) as VARCHAR) + ')'
, src.geo.STBuffer(rn)
FROM ValidLines src
```

Comment: The reason for using MakeValid is to take an invalid geography instance and convert it to a valid one. Even if the MultiLineStrings are invalid, the SQL call to MakeValid() shouldn't crash. The C# call to MakeValid() with the same values doesn't crash.

Comment: 9 lines placed exactly over the top of each other simply can't be made to be valid, the docs even explicitly state that in this instance it can't be made valid.

Comment: @ChrisMiller need to edit my previous  comment, the docs indirectly state that this instance can't be made valid because the overlapping line cross at _an infinite number of points_

Comment: Even when you have a geography instance that can't be made valid, the connection shouldn't crash.

Comment: For the wkt string in the original post, calling MakeValid() from C# will return a valid instance.  I updated my [https://gist.github.com/anotherlab/44a706a3792cf079f1e2512b4695447d](Gist) to include that code.